# Find Twitter friends with Python

Tags: python, twitter

I create a list of Twitter profiles and I want to download their friends (the users they follow).

I registered on Twitter devs, but I cannot do it through the API without authenticate each user.

Do you know any other way which may let me download friends list without putting every user on my list to authenticate?

Answer (score 0):

Try using the streaming API, Twitter doesn't really have a friend list its more like followers. Followers are not necessary consider as friends. You want to start from your profiles and crawl each of follower and get their followers.

```
def extract_followers(user_id, limit):

    cursor = -1
    ids = []
    while cursor != 0:

        # Assume you have some method to make the twitter connection request where you can pass set of userIds)
        response = twitter_connection(ids, cursor)

        if response is not None:
            ids += response['ids']
            cursor = response['next_cursor']

        print >> sys.stderr, 'Fetched %i total ids for %s' % (len(ids), user_id)

        if len(ids) >= limit or response is None:
            break

    return ids
```

Comment: Actually, Twitter dev calls the users you follow as "Friends". And if I understand right, you cannot download this data without putting the user to authenticate. So, I am asking, if you can find the users who follow one only with his id.